# Jquery show and hide bouncing back?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some jquery show and hide, the problem Im having is that is doesnt stay when it shows, it keeps bouncing back out.

Can anybody help? 
Here is a demo 
http://jsfiddle.net/WqYFV/

```
$(".home-phone-icon").click(function () {
    $(".home-nav-phone").slideToggle('slow');
})

$(".home-phone-icon").click(function () {
    $(".home-nav-phone").slideUp('slow');
})
```

Comment: you have added `toggle` as well as `slideup` for the icon, hence first it wil `trigger` the `toggle` function and then slideup function second , which `closes` the `div`. Remove slideup functionality.that should do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two `click` handlers which will handle the same event - the latter of which will hide the `.home-phone-icon` element again. You just need to remove that:

```
$(".home-phone-icon").click(function () {
    $(".home-nav-phone").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WqYFV/1/)

Comment: +1, additionally if he doesn't want .home-nav-phone jumping around as it shows/hides, you could apply a `float:left;` to it

Answer (score 1):

Please remove the second `click` event the below one:

```
$(".home-phone-icon").click(function () {
    $(".home-nav-phone").slideUp('slow');
});
```

and just use the first `click` event

```
$(".home-phone-icon").click(function () {
    $(".home-nav-phone").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/WqYFV/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try only:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".home-phone-icon").click(function () {
    $(".home-nav-phone").slideToggle('slow');
})
});
</script>
<a href="javascript:;" class="home-phone-icon"></a>

<ul class="home-nav-phone">
    <li><a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<style type="text/css">
  .home-phone-icon {
      display: block;
      float: right;
      background: red;
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px;
      position: relative;
      top: -30px;
      right: -8px;
  }
  .home-nav-phone {
      z-index: 9999999;
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      top: 62px;
      left: 0px;
      display:none;
      margin:0 auto;
      pointer:cursor;
  }
  .home-nav-phone li {
      line-height: 45px;
      background:#2e2e2e;
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      z-index: 999;
  }
  .home-nav-phone li a {
      color: white;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
  }
</style>
```